# Globalization in asp.net MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement `Globalization` and `Localization` in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I gone through a couple of tutorials like [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).

But the problem is he is creating multiple views for each language.

So if there are 10 views then we have to create 10 views for each language adding up to 100. Please guide me the best way of creating multilingual(i.e. 8 languages) application with single view and if possible with PO files.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend multiple views.  I like how OpenCart and other software does it.  They have a separate folder for languages.  All controllers actions first call the language method to get the specific language being requested and then return it to the view like any other variable.  Of course, this works well for static content.  For database-driven content, you should have a separate function to fetch the specific field for the language being requested.

Answer (score 1):

Doing multiple views is, in my opinion, the best way to go about it. If you find it too much of a strugle, it's probably because your MVC application is not following a proper MVC pattern. A view should always be dumb. And if a view is dumb, the only thing it has is writtings and layout.

That said, of course you could go about doing a culture service of some sort. All you need is:

- The culture service (Instance, Singleton or Static. That depends on your needs)
- XML files to hold key-value pairs for each string of each language

Pattern

- Application loads
- Instance or Static config the service
- Service loads the appropriate XML based on what ever you want it to
- View calls the service from Context or Static method `@String.Format(Context.CultureService.GetFormat("HELLOWORLD"), "World")`
- Service return a format string like `"Hello %s!"` fetched from the loaded XML

**Edit**

Oh, to allow decimal / currency / date default globalization, you should also consider a `Current` property that returns an instance of the current Culture. That way you can use it like this: `@ViewModel.SomeDate.ToString(Context.CultureService.Current.DateTimeFormat)`

**Edit2**

2 more things.

Because this whole `@String.Format(Context.CultureService.GetFormat(), "")` thing is so long, consider writing a helper so that you can write something like `@Globalize("HELLOWORLD", "World")`

Consider using Enums to generalize the strings data. It will be much cleaner in views by getting rid of magic strings and it will allow easier refactoring. Result could be something like `@Globalize(HOME.Hello, User.Name)`